# Kendo UI: Remove the Radio Button Glow After Clicked

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI (MVC) to create a radio button which works fine after some position tweaks. There is, however, an annoying glow that surrounds the radio button after it has been clicked. It is only visible when the radio button still has focus and the mouse is no longer hovering over the radio button. I have looked at the styles in Chrome developer tools and I am unable to locate where this style is being applied. A picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

You can find a "live" example of what I am talking about [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styling/radios) after selecting the "moonlight" theme (click "Change Theme" in the upper right corner.) In that example the selected radio button turns orange when the mouse is no longer hovering over the selected item.

I have also looked at the four element states that chrome provides (:active, :focus, :hover, :visited) and none of these seem to have the style that I am looking for (along with not even showing the same behavior.)

I am still pretty new to the web side of things so it is very possible I am missing something, I just wish I knew what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the demo page you provided the style you are looking for is this:

```
.k-radio:focus+.k-radio-label:before {
    border-color: #f9b303;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #f4af03;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #f4af03;
}
```

The style is applied on `:focus` of the radio button to the `:before` puesdo element of the immediately preceding `.k-radio-label`

Simply create a new style targeting this and set `box-shadow: none;`

Comment: This still isn't working for me. The radio button still glows orange when the mouse is not hovering over the selected item. It looks like the radio button border color is being changed. In the example I was able to prevent the orange glow by changing the border color but that does not fix the problem in my application. I'll edit the question with more information when I get a chance.

Comment: The above is indeed the correct answer (specifically the box shadow.) When the problem was not as exaggerated in Kendo Dojo as it was in my application I went looking for the theme we use. Turns out this was a problem of our own making and the problem was located in the same style tags as your answer. I just could not locate the style because when I switched to Chrome dev tools the element was no longer in focus so the style no longer applied.